# PHP Array doesn't show all items

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code for an array, and the problem is that it shows only two last items of the array.

```
$svi= array(
        $WMN1,
        $LNG1,
        $SSWN1,
        $DT1,
        $OET1,
        $OW1,
        $NT1  
    );

    $imena_sajtova = array(
        'Prvi WMN',
        'Drugi LNG',
        'Treci SSWN',
        'Cetvrti DT',
        'Peti OET',
        'Sesti OW',
        'Sedmi NT'
    );

    $novi_svi =array_combine($svi, $imena_sajtova);

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($novi_svi); echo '</pre>';
```

And the result of this code is:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Sedmi NT
    [1] => Sesti OW
)
```

What could be a problem? Thanks!

var_dump($svi) displays this:

```
array(7) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(1) [3]=> int(1) [4]=> int(2) [5]=> int(1) [6]=> int(2) }
```

---

This $svi array has results from some functions:

```
$WMN1=RSS_Brojac($WMN);
$LNG1=RSS_Brojac($LNG);
$SSWN1=RSS_Brojac($SSWN);
$DT1=RSS_Brojac($DT);
$OET1=RSS_Brojac($OET);
$OW1=RSS_Brojac($OW);
$NT1=RSS_Brojac($NT);
```

I've changed order of arrays in the array_combine, and it works!

```
$novi_svi =array_combine($imena_sajtova, $svi);

    arsort($novi_svi);


    echo '<pre>'; print_r($novi_svi); echo '</pre>';
```

And the output of this code is:

```
Array
(
    [Prvi WMN] => 2
    [Sedmi NT] => 2
    [Peti OET] => 2
    [Sesti OW] => 1
    [Cetvrti DT] => 1
    [Drugi LNG] => 1
    [Treci SSWN] => 1
)
```

I'have sorted them from high to low, that's what I actually wanted to do with this array.
Now, how to separate the results, to have them in separate divs inside html?
So then, I'll be able to change their style and create some kind of table with these results.

The results are output from some RSS feeds, which I use to count number of published news.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `var_dump($svi);` --- we have no idea what's inside of that array. But seems like those are not unique numbers

Comment: Inside of that array are some functions:  

         $WMN1=RSS_Brojac($WMN);
  $LNG1=RSS_Brojac($LNG);
  $SSWN1=RSS_Brojac($SSWN);
  $DT1=RSS_Brojac($DT);
  $OET1=RSS_Brojac($OET);
  $OW1=RSS_Brojac($OW);
  $NT1=RSS_Brojac($NT);

Comment: @Adnan Edit the question instead of writing it as comment. It's unreadable :-(

Comment: Please put the exact output of `var_dump($svi);` --- I've asked it with purpose

Comment: Edited, @Luc M,
Updated with the output zerkms
Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, yes, that's what array_combine does. What output do you actually want?

Comment: @MattGibson I've updated the code. It is almost complete. Thank you Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there you go, the exact reason why you only retrieve two values after the array combine is because you've only supplied two unique integers, `1,2` as the indexes of the arrays to be combined. You need at least 7 unique values for your 7 strings.

[Here's an example using your code and it doesn't work](https://eval.in/216318)

And...[Here's an example using 7 unique indexes, that does work](https://eval.in/216319)

Comment: Yeah, you're totally right. That was the problem! Thanks @Ohgodwhy.
I'm almost done with the app, but I need some additional help with this code. I've posted an update. :)

Comment: @Adnan Please create a new question and roll back the edit. This isn't a forum-style website with long threads, that's what makes it unique. :)

Answer (score 0):

Typecast the values in the first array before merge. Can be achieved with array_map(). I assume you know the desired types in the variables.